# How to send value from python script to console and exit

Tags: python

My python script generate a proper command that user need to run in the same console. My scenario is that user is running a script and then as a result see the command that must to run. Is there any way to exit python script and send that command to console, so user do not need to copy/paste?

Comment: Why not just use `subprocess` to execute the command without the user having to press Enter?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? What version are you using? What minor version, more specifically?

Comment: The answer may depend on the operation system and/or command line you are using. In Linux, you could just pipe the output of the script to a shell interpreter: `python script.py | sh`

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to have your python script (let's call it `script.py`) just *print* the command: `print('ls -l')` and use it in a terminal like so: `$(python3 script.py)`. This makes bash run the output of your script as a command, and would basically run a `ls -l` in the terminal.

You can even go a step beyond and create an alias in `~/.bashrc` so that you no longer need to call the whole line. You can write at the end of the file something like `alias printls=$(python3 /path/to/script.py)`. After starting a new terminal, you can type `printls` and the script will run.

A drawback of this method is that you have no proper way of handling exceptions or errors in your code, since everything it prints will be run as a command. One way (though ugly) would be to `print('echo "An error occured!"')` so that the user who runs the command can see that something malfunctioned.

However, I'd suggest going for the "traditional" way and running the command directly from python. Here's a link to how you can achieve this: [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Python can run system commands in new subshells. The proper way of doing this is via the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, but for simple tasks it's easier to just use `os.system`. Example Python script (assuming a Unix-like system):

```
import os
os.system('ls')
```